# Move parameter to local variable and LEA instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

Does anyone knows what's the wrong solution here:

```
func PROC x:sdword, y:sdword
LOCAL tmp: sdword
...
func ENDP
```

- A. `mov tmp, y`
- B. `mov eax, y`
- C. `mov tmp, ecx`
- D. `lea eax, tmp`

Can I use all these instructions or there is any of them which is invalid??

Best Regards and thank you

Comment: wrong solution for *what*?

Comment: Which instruction is wrong.

Comment: If I wanted to replace '...' for one of those instructions, which one is wrong?

Comment: Wrong logically, syntactically? What is this function trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want to achieve any function. I just want to know some more syntax. Giving that example can I do all the 4 instructions? I guess the LEA one is the wrong one but I'm not sure. I just want to know which one is invalid.

Comment: Yes, I would agree that the `lea` instruction would be incorrect here since its used in a manner other than its supposed to. The `mov`s transfer data, The `lea` is typically used with brackets (`[]`) to calculate an address, which in this case is not doing so. Does this help?

Comment: `mov tmp, y` is wrong. Assuming MASM and the 32-bit C calling convention, `tmp` will be translated to `[ebp-4]` and `y` will be translated to `[ebp+12]`. The result is `mov [ebp-4], [ebp+12]` - a memory-to-memory-operation. A x86 processor cannot perform such operations.

Answer (score 0):

Since the objective is to understand better, see if the following illuminates the underlying ideas :

```
1. mov y,tmp ; This is not legal in Intel x64 (or x86)
2. mov eax,y ; This is perfectly fine. An advice : use mov eax, dword ptr y
3. mov tmp,ecx  ; again, is perfectly fine. However, mov dword ptr tmp,ecx is easier to track during debugging
4. lea eax,tmp ; This is not wrong - only this loads the address of the variable tmp into eax, if your next instruction would have been, say
4' : mov ecx, dword ptr [eax], you would be loading the content of the memory address tmp into ecx.
```

Trust this clarifies.